# Confusion regarding fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

i am confused about fundamental theorem of calculus. One part of it states that the antiderivative of $f(x)$ is defined as $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$.
I am confused about the a, is it the same as the $+c$ that we write when computing an indefinite integral?

For Example: Lets look at $f(t)=t^2$, then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt=\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{3}a^3$,
is this equivalent to $F(x) = \frac{1}{3}x^3 +C $?

Comment: Indefinite integral, in fact, is set of functions , where the derivative of each element is equal to $f$ and  $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is element of this set with specific $C=- \frac{1}{3}a^3$.

Comment: Yes, any choice of $a$ gives you an antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Short answer: yes the $a$ and the $C$ are essentially equivalent. There is a subtle distinction someone will probably put in an answer. I think it's on this site elsewhere too.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is everywhere continuous? Are you applying this just on an interval containing $a$? (The “$+C$” yoga requires that you are working on *one* interval only.)

Comment: The $a$ is **not** equivalent to $+C$. Consider any probability distribution: you can only add or subtract at most $1$ by changing $a$, but with $+C$ you can add any constant. Please **edit** the question and copy the exact text of your definition (preferably both parts) and the source (textbook and author name) so we all can know exactly what we’re dealing with.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at the part that defines the definite integral rather than the general antiderivative.